# $L^2(\Omega)/\Bbb{R}$ in cited reference?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, notation

The following is a theorem in the preliminary material section of Constantin and Foias's "Navier-Stokes Equations":

> Let $\Omega\subset\Bbb{R}^n$ be an open bounded set with locally
>   Lipschitz boundary.
>
> - If a distribution $p\in D'(\Omega)$ has all its first derivatives $D_ip$ in $L^2(\Omega)$ then $p\in L^2(\Omega)$ and 
>     $$
>    \|p\|_{L^2(\Omega)/\Bbb{R}}\leq C(\Omega)\|\nabla p\|_{L^2(\Omega)^n}
>    $$
> - If a distribution $p$ has all its first derivatives in    $H^{-1}(\Omega)$ then $p\in L^2(\Omega)$ and 
>     $$   
>    \|p\|_{L^2(\Omega)/\Bbb{R}}\leq C(\Omega)\|\nabla
>    p\|_{H^{-1}(\Omega)^n}    $$
>
> In both cases, if no restriction is imposed on $\partial\Omega$ it
>   follows that $p\in L_{\hbox{loc}}^2(\Omega)$. By
>   $\|p\|_{L^2(\Omega)/\Bbb{R}}$ we mean $$
>  \inf_{c\in\Bbb{R}}\|p-c\|_{L^2(\Omega)}= \|p-\frac{\int_\Omega p \
>  dx}{|\Omega|}\cdot 1\|_{L^2(\Omega)}. $$

The space $L^2(\Omega)/\Bbb{R}$ defined in the theorem looks quite strange to me (since the notation usually suggests a quotient space). 
Could anyone come up with a cited reference about this space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *is* a quotient space!

$\mathbb{R}$ here should be thought of as the one-dimensional subspace of $L^2(\Omega)$ which consists of the (a.e.) constant functions.  The norm given is the canonical norm on the quotient of a Banach space mod a closed subspace.  This construction is discussed, for instance, in section III.4 of Conway's *A Course in Functional Analysis*.

Strictly speaking, $\|p\|_{L^2(\Omega)/ \mathbb{R}}$ is not really the norm of $p$, but the norm of the coset $p + \mathbb{R}$ in the quotient space.  It's an easy exercise to check it is well defined.